# Who are the three Homunculi that are with Irisviel and Saber?

Tags: fate-zero

In Fate/Zero, when Irisviel and Saber arrive in Fuyuki in episode 3 they are accompanied by three Homunculi maids.

One of the three had slightly curvy hair coming from her hood which makes be think it was [Leysritt](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Leysritt) and I assume where she is, [Sella](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Sella) would be close by.

I am looking for confirmation of who these three Homunculi Maids are. If two of them are Leysritt and Sella, what happened to the third that prevents her from serving Ilya?

Comment: It's about halfway through episode 3, actually. In the LN (volume 1, act 3, -162:27:03; p. 246 of the 4-vol edition), it only mentions there being two maids. No idea why there are three in the anime. I don't recall the maids being named at any point in the LN, but I'm pretty sure the implication is that they're supposed to be Sella and Leysritt.

Comment: @senshin i got confused on the episode since episode 1 was so long. at first we see only 2 at the baggage claim however when Saber is talking to Irisviel about her appearance there is a third maid with the group (i think the first time is when their on the escalator)

Comment: @Memor-X a screenshot would probably help a lot

Answer (score 1):

This only partially answers the question. However, in both of their Wikia pages, under **Appearance** it states that Leysritt and Sella are in fact 2 years old.

> Despite her appearance, she is only about two years old.

Sources: [Leysritt](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Leysritt#Appearance)/[Sella](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Sella#Appearance) - Appearance <sup>*exact same wording on both pages</sup>

Given there is no mention on either of their pages, of them being in Fate/Zero I would assume this would be referring to their appearance in Fate/Stay Night which would make it impossible for them to have appeared in Fate/Zero which is set 10 years prior to Fate/Stay Night.